# Putting a tree next to another tree

Tags: tikz-trees, trees

How can I put example tree (a) and example tree (b) next to each other on the page? At the moment, tree (b) appears below tree (a):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}   
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}
\usepackage{ulem}

\begin{document}
\ex. \a. \begin{tikzpicture} \Tree [.DP [.N Pat ] ] \end{tikzpicture} 
\b.  \label{VP} \begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree [.VP  [.V saw ] [.DP [.N Kim ] ]]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code contains a few errors (`\ex`, `\a` and `\b` should not have backslashes). After correcting this, the code compiles fine and the trees are put one next to the other.

Comment: @PhilippImhof, those commands are from the `linguex` package, which should be loaded in the preamble. Then it compiles as the @user65526 describes.

Comment: @Jason: Oh, I see, thanks. And now I can see the problem. I would suggest to use `multicols` just like exposed in Gonzalo's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `multicols` environment from [`multicol`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol) package.

The example below shows your original `tikz-qtree` code and a version using the  powerful [`forest`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest) package; in both cases, alignment was improved using the `baseline` option:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}   
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}

\ex. 
\a. \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline] \Tree [.DP [.N Pat ] ] \end{tikzpicture}
\b.  \label{VP} \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\Tree [.VP  [.V saw ] [.DP [.N Kim ] ]]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{multicols}

\begin{multicols}{2}

\ex. 
\a. 
\begin{forest}
baseline 
[DP 
  [N 
    [Pat]
  ]   
] 
\end{forest}
\b.  \label{VP} 
\begin{forest}
baseline
[VP  
  [V
    [saw] 
  ]
  [DP
    [N
      [Kim] 
    ]
  ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Although everyone here is a big fan of `forest` (and I agree it's a great package) for most linguistic trees `tikz-qtree` does a fine job, and in fact produces nicer looking trees depending on the particular tree being drawn. For example in this question, [Extending a tree](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/257289) the packing algorithm of `forest` produces a very hard to read and odd looking tree from a linguistics point of view. (Also the default edge path in `forest` is quite ugly and not used generally in linguistics.)

Comment: @AlanMunn I changed the wording of my answer. Now I just present `forest` as another possibility without suggesting to switch to it.

Comment: You beat me to it, @AlanMunn. I actually did switch from `tikz-qtree` to `forest` (mostly because of [this error](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86432/42880) and the occasional need for more compact trees), but I have to use several styles to get the `forest` trees to look appropriate for linguistics. And many times I find myself overriding the alignment issues you pointed out in [Extending a tree](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257289/extending-a-tree) using `fit=band`. I usually recommend `tikz-qtree` to students because it works out of the box, unlike `forest`.

Comment: @JasonZentz Thanks Jason. I've added a meta question to make the point more generally. [Not seeing the forest for the trees](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/6248)